# Core Data equivalent for sqlite query

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I use Core Data for an iPhone app.
There is "Flight" entity with a "start" and "duration" property.
The flights are listed on a paginated view, where I need to sum the duration per page and the duration rollup sum.
In native sqlite following solution works:

```
select sum(pg.zduration) from (select zduration,zstart from zflight order by zstart limit %i,%i) as pg",offset,limit
```

- So on first page, with a page size of 5, I get duration sum and same rollup duration with offset=0 and limit=5.
- On second page, I get the duration sum with offset=5 and limit=5. The rollup sum with offset=0 and limit=10.
  And so on..

**Now the Question:**

How would I solve that with Core Data, NSExpression, NSExpressionDescription and NSFetchRequest instead of sqlite? Of course, I would not like to load all flight objects in memory...

So I am able to caculate the duration for all flights:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Flight" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSSortDescriptor *startSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start"
                                                                    ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:startSortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

request.fetchOffset=onPage*pageSize;//does not help, cause offset and limit are applied to the result
request.fetchLimit=pageSize;//does not help, cause offset and limit are applied to the result

NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"duration"];    
NSExpression *sumExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];

// Create an expression description using the minExpression and returning a date.
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription1 = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];    
[expressionDescription1 setName:@"durationSum"];
[expressionDescription1 setExpression:sumExpression];
[expressionDescription1 setExpressionResultType:NSInteger64AttributeType];


[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:expressionDescription1,nil]];

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if(error!=nil){
    [NSException raise:@"Sum Page Duration failed" format:@"%@ Error:%@", [[error userInfo] valueForKey:@"reason"],error];        
}

if (objects!=nil && [objects count] > 0) {
    return (NSNumber*)[[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"durationSum"];
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the limit and offset set on the fetch request are applied to the result and `NSExpression` won't work well in this case. You could operate on the returned objects, after they've been offset and limited by the fetch request, using a [collection operator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) rather than `NSExpression`, e.g.:

```
NSNumber *durationSum = [objects valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.duration"];
```